# How to enable personal Gmail signing in full managed devices in AMAPI?

Tags: android, android-management-api

I need to enable a setting where users can personally sign in or sign up their personal Gmail id. Currently, when they try to sign-in or sign up it ask them to enter only work id only.  How to enable personal Gmail signing in full managed devices?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to enable personal Gmail sign-ins directly on fully managed devices, as these devices treat all accounts as work accounts without a separate personal profile. If you want users to sign in with their personal Gmail IDs, you might consider utilizing [company-owned devices for work and personal use](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#company-owned_devices_for_work_and_personal_use).